# Shape coding in MPEG-4 Part 2 (MPEG-4 Visual)

Tags: h.264, mpeg-4, video-codecs

Can someone explain what was the original motivation behind using [shape coding](http://www.sandeepkbhat.info/shared/Courses/Winter2008/ECE242/Sandeep_ECE242Report.pdf) in MPEG-4 Part 2 and why it was later not implemented/removed in MPEG-4 Part 10 (H.264)?

I already read the excellent answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800015/mpeg-4-part-2-had-some-awesome-face-and-body-motion-concepts-but-they-disappe), so I know that they both codecs were not exactly designed by same group of people. However, I wonder why the idea of shape coding was completely left aside since it seems to involve a lot of intricate, well-thought details to me. Was the reasons mainly computational or did people figure out that other schemes would bring better quality?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is mainly computational. The best example is to look at hardware encoders/decoders.
H.264 encoders/decoders have been integrated into many devices, e.g. mobile phones, blu-ray players, etc. This would probably have been very complicated if the hardware designers had had to deal with intricate schemes such as shape coding.